# Display elements inline on Card

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help to display elements horizontally in a card compared to default (one below the other)

Currently, my card looks like the below image:

However, I need it to display elements inline.

```html
    <div class="ibm-col-12-2 card1" >
                                    <div class="ibm-card">
                                        <div class="ibm-card__image">
                                            <img src="https://cdn.kalingatv.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/ibm.png" alt="card_3" width="300" height="170" class="ibm-resize"></div>
                                        <div class="ibm-card__content">
                                            <h4 class="ibm-h4">Gain transactional insights</h4>
                                            <p>Use AI to rapidly find and visualize complete supply chain transactions</p>
                                            <p class="ibm-ind-link">
                                                <a href="javascript:;" class="ibm-forward-link ibm-light">Explore</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: what are the styles you're using for all of the classes here?

Comment: internal classes similar to bootstrap @Jhecht

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allow CSS3, you could go with using a flexbox layout. Style `.ibm-card` with `display: flex;` and the text will automatically be placed to the right of the image.

There is a lot of information available online regarding the flexbox layout, you can for example check out [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp.).

```html
    <div class="ibm-col-12-2 card1" >
                                    <div class="ibm-card" style="display: flex;">
                                        <div class="ibm-card__image">
                                            <img src="https://cdn.kalingatv.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/ibm.png" alt="card_3" width="300" height="170" class="ibm-resize"></div>
                                        <div class="ibm-card__content">
                                            <h4 class="ibm-h4">Gain transactional insights</h4>
                                            <p>Use AI to rapidly find and visualize complete supply chain transactions</p>
                                            <p class="ibm-ind-link">
                                                <a href="javascript:;" class="ibm-forward-link ibm-light">Explore</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```